# Time Differences

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time

I have two columns in SharePoint that are each Single Line of Text columns that require the user to enter the start and end time of an audit, utilizing a 24-hour clock.

For example, the User enters "`14:00`" into start time and "`14:26`" into end time. I then created a Total Time Taken column that utilizes this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(HOUR([FMC Audit End Time]-[FMC Audit Start Time]),"#"),":",TEXT(MINUTE([FMC Audit End Time]-[FMC Audit Start Time]),"#"))
```

The problem is that if the start time is `14:00` and the end time is `14:05`, it reflects the response as "`:5`".

How can I correct this formula so that if it is single digits, it will show as "`:05`"?

Is there a better way to capture this data? I did not want to capture the date, only the time.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Updated to match comments' requests**

If you update your calculation to use the formula `=TEXT(Start-End,"H:MM")` (*This will take the place of your entire existing formula*), it will return `0:05`instead of `:5`.

The `TEXT` formula doesn't play nicely with leading 0's unless a complete H:MM date/time format is used.

Comment: Hi Vanblart - thank you for the response.  I had tried this initially in my testing on this and that did not have an impact on the result.  14:10 start and 14:18 end time still resulted in :8 and not :08.

Comment: Is it okay if instead of `:05` it would display as `0:05`?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to outline this instead! And just to make sure I was clear, the `=TEXT` function I provide will replace your entire `=CONCATENATE( ... )` function :)

Comment: The "Text" code you provided above worked EXACTLY how needed.  Thank you, Vanblart!  I tried +1 the answer, but since I'm less than 15, it won't show publicly.